# Display months on a drop down calendar as TEXT instead of Numbers

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-gravity-forms

Trying to display MONTHS as TEXT (Juanuary) instead of NUMBER (1) in a drop down calendar (gravity form)
I tried this code but if you select a MONTH and then press a button into the FORM it will display the month as number again.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
         $('.gfield_date_dropdown_month select option').each( function(i, option) {
            switch( option.value ) {
               case '1': option.innerHTML = 'January'; break;
               case '2': option.innerHTML = 'February'; break;
               case '3': option.innerHTML = 'March'; break;
               case '4': option.innerHTML = 'April'; break;
               case '5': option.innerHTML = 'May'; break;
               case '6': option.innerHTML = 'June'; break;
               case '7': option.innerHTML = 'July'; break;
               case '8': option.innerHTML = 'August'; break;
               case '9': option.innerHTML = 'September'; break;
               case '10': option.innerHTML = 'October'; break;
               case '11': option.innerHTML = 'November'; break;
               case '12': option.innerHTML = 'December'; break;
            }
         });
      });
   </script>

<?php } );
```

Comment: anyone could help me?